# How can I calculate y2 given angle in degrees, x1, y1 and x2?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a line having a 5 degree angle, x1 equal to 100, y1 equal to 0, x2 equal to 0, how do I determine the value of y2?

[Example Illustration (corrected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kWDP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the angle marked in your image is actually $85$ degrees, $y_2=100\tan 5° \approx 8.7$

Comment: Thank you. This solution is perfect. And yes, the angle in the original illustration was mislabeled as 45 degrees. It has been corrected in the question.